# How to find weekly sum from daily data in SAS?

Tags: sas

I found it is quite inconvenient to do row operations in SAS.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PROC EXPAND, which despite what the name suggests, can also go from higher frequency intervals to lower ones.

http://support.sas.com/rnd/app/examples/ets/expa/index.htm

There will indeed be some oddball values. If you want to correct for that, you might run a data step what involves something like:

`IF variable <= 0.01 then variable = 0`  where you choose 0.01 or whatever based on a clear break in your mind between a "real" small number and an artifact of PROC EXPAND.

Comment: Thanks! It works! 
But for some zero sum rows, SAS will set some weird value instead of assigning zeros(e.g. -1.82906E-20) 
How can I get rid of it?